# How should I deploy an MFC application?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, winapi, mfc

I created an application in VS 2008 Express as an MFC app just to take advantage of the easy GUI creation. I might re-do this app in pure win32 since no other MFC classes are used (just a button and a text box, the button fires off the main program, all win32). My only question that determines whether I stay in MFC or port it over to pure win32 is this:

How difficult is it to deploy an MFC app? What do I need to do (in VS 2008) to make sure it works on another machine?

Comment: The Express edition doesn't include MFC.  Are you perhaps talking about Windows Forms?

Comment: I created an MFC application... Maybe I am not on Express after all. ?? Can't remember exactly and I'm not near the computer that has VS 2008 installed right now...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Statically link MFC  and it's just another .exe.
You can just give that to the user or create an installer with either the microsoft .msi tool or a regular setup.exe with something like [innosetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/).

Edit - the error message in your comment is about another dll that is part of a 3rd party library. You can't (easily) take a DLL and incorporate it into your app. the licensing may also require you to ship their DLL as a separate lib.

Comment: How do I statically link? I looked in the project Properties -> Link but could not find anything.

Comment: somewhere in the linker options it says "use MFC in dynamic library" change this to select "use MFC in static library"

Comment: Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> General -> Use of MFC = "Use MFC in a Static Library"

Comment: Thanks dcm - I was on a Linux machine and posting from memory

Comment: Hm, I did all of this buy I am getting: The Application failed to start because cv110.dll was not found. Re-Installing the applicaiton may fix this problem. I simply took the exe and attempted to run it on another machine...

Comment: cv110.dll isn't MFC it's part of OpenCV image library. You will have to supply this (and any other openCV dlls) along with your app.

Comment: ps. Have you looked at just using highgui (the simple OpenCV display widget) rather than using MFC?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Visual Studio Merge modules. These can be added while building the installer.
Merge modules provide all the dlls, files required to run your application.